# How to use a ListView with custom item QML

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qtquick2

I am a newbie in QML. I made thanks to internet ressources this **accordion**:

```
Item {
    default property var contentItem: null
    property string title: "panel"
    id: root
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    height: 30
    Layout.fillHeight: current
    property bool current: false
    ColumnLayout {

        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 0
        Rectangle {
            Drag.active: dragArea.drag.active
            id: bar
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            height: 30
            color:  root.current ? "#81BEF7" : "#CEECF5"
            Text {
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.margins: 10
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                text: root.title
            }
            Text {
                anchors{
                    right: parent.right
                    top: parent.top
                    bottom: parent.bottom
                    margins: 10
                }
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                text: "^"
                rotation: root.current ? "180" : 0
            }
            MouseArea {
                id: dragArea
                anchors.fill: parent
                cursorShape: Qt.PointingHandCursor
                drag.axis: Drag.YAxis

                drag.target: root

                onReleased: {

                    root.Drag.drop()
                }
                onClicked: {
                    if (root.parent.current !== root) {

                        root.current = !root.current;

                        root.parent.currentItem = root;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: container
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            anchors.top: bar.bottom
            implicitHeight: root.height - bar.height
            clip: true
            Behavior on implicitHeight {
                PropertyAnimation { duration: 100 }
            }
        }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            if(root.contentItem !== null)
               root.contentItem.parent = container;
        }
    }
}
```

*PanelItem.qml*

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 400; height: 400

        ColumnLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent
            spacing: 1
            id: test
            property var currentItem: null
            PanelItem {
                title: "Panel 1"
                Rectangle {
                    color: "orange"
                    anchors.fill: parent
                }
            }
            PanelItem {
                title: "Panel 2"
                Rectangle {
                    color: "lightgreen"
                    anchors.fill: parent
                }
            }
            PanelItem {
                title: "Panel 3"
                Rectangle {
                    color: "lightblue"
                    anchors.fill: parent
                }
            }
            PanelItem {
                title: "Panel 4"
                Rectangle {
                    color: "yellow"
                    anchors.fill: parent
                }
            }
            Item {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
            }
        }
}
```

*main.qml*

However, I wanted to be able to **change items index** (position) thanks to a "drag & drop" technique.

I read that it is not so good and easy to change index in a column layout. 
So I tried to put my accordion in a **ListView** but I am lost and it doesn't work at all.

I tried something like that:

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 400; height: 400
    ListView {
        id: my_list
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: 14
        delegate: PanelItem {
                id: my_delegate
                title: "Panel 1"
                Rectangle {
                    color: "orange"
                    anchors.fill: parent
                }
        }
    }
}
```

*main.qml*

Could someone help me to do and explain what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: A `ListView` is no `Layout`, so the attached property `Layout` you use in your delegate (e.g. `Layout.fillWidth: true`) should not be available. Try to substitute this by anchors to the left and the right the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, some problems here:

1. If you have your `PanelItem` not in a `*Layout`, you can't use the attached properties `Layout.*`. Therefore lines, such as *Line 5*: `Layout.fillWidth = true` won't work. Use `width: parent.width` or `anchors { left: parent.left; right: parent.rigth }` to set the width.
2. I would not reccomend to use `default property var contentItem`, as this might lead to some forgotten objects. You can assign mutliple `Items` to this default property, where each new `Item` kicks out the former `Item`.
3. Use a `property Component contentItem` instead, as e.g the `QtQuick.Controls 2.0` do. Then use a `Loader` to instantiate this `Component`, when the `PanelItem` is expanded.
   Use a `property Item contentItem` if it should not be dynamicaly loaded and unloaded.
   Using the properties not as `default` makes sure, there is usually only one `Item` assigned.
   Usually it is only recommended to use the `default property` only together with something like `alias someItem.data`. If you use `default property var someData` you should listen to `onSomeDataChanged` and reassign the newly added object to some appropriate container.
   So if you want to allow multiple Items to be added, make it like this:

> example.qml

```
Item {
    default property alias contentItem.data
    Item {
        id: contentItem
        width: childrenRect.width
        height: childrenRect.height
    }
}
```

Use some line such as `implicitHeight: barHeight + contentItemHeight` where `barHeight` is the height of the bar, that is always visible, and the `contentItemHeight` is `(collapsed ? 0 : loadedContentItem.height)`

You might use a `ObjectModel` if it is just for the sake of reordering of the `Item`s. Then you should not provide a delegate, as the `ObjectModel` supplies the *`delegate`* itself - or well rather the Object to be displayed than a delegate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am a beginner so I will spend some times to understand what you said and how to apply it. But I will come back when I did ! :)