# QML - How to insert an Item at any position in StackLayout?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols2

I need to add a component at a particular position in stack layout and I am not getting how to insert, following is the code.

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Component{
    id:comp
    Rectangle{
        id:rect
        anchors.fill:parent
    }
}

StackLayout
{
    id:stack
    anchors.fill:parent

    currentIndex:index //spin box will update this property 
}

Button
{
    id:insert
    onClicked:
    {
        var res = comp.createObject(stack) // Should insert a rect at a position not at the end
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer and also may be duplicate of:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43225476/6336374

I used [`insert(index,item)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-objectmodel.html#insert-method) of [`ObjectModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-objectmodel.html)

Thanks to @derM it helped a lot.